# How can you show real target of intermediaate redirect link on hover?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a number of redirect links that are intended to track clicks, but I want them to show up in browser on hover as their target.

This site does it for their sponsored links -- the More from Our Partners Section.

http://blog.outbrain.com/2011/04/finding-an-audience-on-twitter-and-the-post-social-content-marketing-challenge.html#more-1209

If you hover on a link such as 15 Most Followed Chefs on Twitter, you see the target url such as livestrong.com -- but if you look at the link it is actually: http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?key=72ecf1d1c22d4bcb6731a0e5c2902d43&rdid=202267155&type=CAD_def_stg&in-site=false&pc_id=2739633&req_id=89132213e0fd8071bc6b6d01992ac802&agent=blog_JS_rec&recMode=4&reqType=1&wid=1&imgType=0&version=37492&idx=7

(this behavior stops working if you copy the url).

Is something done via on hover in javascript or in CSS?

Appreciate any help you might give.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one of the links:

```
<a class="rec-link" target="_blank" href="http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?key=19a1628a9cad0f9f4ac60304d3207ea2&amp;rdid=202267155&amp;type=RPM_def_ch&amp;in-site=false&amp;pc_id=1944349&amp;req_id=1f0e47434afb7b8d70f06f9809ef9bf3&amp;agent=blog_JS_rec&amp;recMode=4&amp;reqType=1&amp;wid=1&amp;imgType=0&amp;version=37492&amp;idx=8" onmousedown="this.href='http://paid.outbrain.com/network/redir?key=19a1628a9cad0f9f4ac60304d3207ea2&amp;rdid=202267155&amp;type=RPM_def_ch&amp;in-site=false&amp;pc_id=1944349&amp;req_id=1f0e47434afb7b8d70f06f9809ef9bf3&amp;agent=blog_JS_rec&amp;recMode=4&amp;reqType=1&amp;wid=1&amp;imgType=0&amp;version=37492&amp;idx=8';return true;" onclick="javascript:return(true)">Gmail lesson: Don't use stats to minimize angry users</a>
```

As you can see (?) there is a `href` attribute and an `onmousedown` event. It's that simple. Make the `href` nice and the `this.href=...` long.

**edit**
They use `onmousedown` because that's also triggered by the right mouse button. (`click` only by left)